# Limit the rotation of mesh THREE.js

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

What is the limit to rotating a object in Three.js? I want to know to be able to reset the meshes rotation back to zero instead of it going on and on with larger numbers, I have the following code

`maxRotation = ?;//What is the max
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    if(mesh.rotation.y >= maxRotation)
    {
        mesh.rotation.y = 0;
    }`

As it increases the y, it never reaches a point where the rotation resets it just goes on and on, I though the limit was 360 rotation and then to zero but its different in 3D.
If this is a bad question please do not -rep me, just tell me and I take the question down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single rotation would be 360 degrees or `Math.PI * 2`.
You can rotate multiple times, but if you want to reset, PI * 2 should be it.

```
var maxRotation = Math.PI * 2;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    if(mesh.rotation.y >= maxRotation)
    {
        mesh.rotation.y = 0;
    }
```

Also, you may want to store maxRotation once, when you setup your variables

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically there is no such thing as max rotation, because it is kind of periodic function. Meaning that after certain point of rotation you will get to the starting point and continue "new" rotation. But if you are asking when that point is reached then it is either 360 degrees or mathematically 2 * Math.PI (those two are equivalent) but PI notation is preffered.

Just to demonstrate, after 2 * Math.PI you will get to starting point therefore 2 * Math.PI is equivalent to 0 rotation as well as 4 * Math.PI (basically each 2k * Math.PI is equivalent to 0, where k is any possitive integer including 0).